# Type 'number[]' cannot be used as an index type

Tags: typescript

```
const groupAnagrams = (arr: string[]) => {
    const hash: { [key: number]: string[] } = {};

    arr.forEach((str) => {
        // Here you can see count type 
        const count: number[] = Array(26).fill(0);

        for (let char of str) {
            count[char.charCodeAt(0) - "a".charCodeAt(0)] += 1;
        }

        if (hash[count]) {
            hash[count] = hash[count].concat(str);
        } else {
            hash[count] = [str];
        }
    });

    return Object.entries(hash).map(([_, arr]) => arr);
};
```

In the code snippet above, you can see where I want to use `number` array as a `string`, and TypeScript has other plans on this. When you assign array as an object `key`, it implicitly convert it to string `[1,2,3] => '1,2,3'`. How can I make it work, without assigning to count `any`?

Comment: `hash[count]` is trying to use `count` (which is `number[]`) to index `hash`, which is defined as having `number` keys (not `number[]` keys, which you can't have in an interface anyway).

Comment: yes, I understand it ) how can I make it work ? join array first ? [1.2,3].join() and assign it as a sting ?

Comment: or just convert it to string => count.toString()

Comment: Most likely yes. Is this where your other question about time complexity comes from?

Comment: @catgirlkelly yes, and as i see , time complexity of those 2 methods is the same